# SSRS Report Parameter Default Null Value not Applied

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2014

I have a SSRS report with a single integer parameter.

Using Report Builder I've:

- changed the parameter to allow null values.
- set the default value to Null.
- saved the report.

However, when the report is requested from the server, the parameter is empty (rather than Null) and the Null checkbox isn't ticked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even though the report was being saved with the change, this wasn't being observed when it was rendered and returned by the server.

I had to use 'Save As' to save the report as a different name to get the change to apply.  I could then delete the original report and rename the revised report to that of the original.

Comment: Sometimes when you save over a report, it doesn't updated the default values that were stored on the server. This is because you can customize the defaults there just like the data source.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by clicking on the drop-down menu to the right of the report name (on the SSRS report page). Select "Manage" > Select "Parameters" tab > check the "Has Default" boxes for the parameters that show "Null" as the default values. This fixed it for me.